# Aptana launches new Aptana instance when double-clicking a PHP file

Tags: eclipse, ide, aptana

This happens until I right-click and open the file once by selecting "Open with > Text editor". Subsequent double-clicks on *that* PHP file will open in the same Aptana instance. Any ideas about how to fix this?

Comment: Figured it out; Aptana doesn't recognize PHP files by default. I *think* that, once I open a single file, Aptana learns that THAT file should be opened with the given editor (in this case the Text editor). Otherwise, I assume it defaults to Windows' interpretation of the associated editor, leaving the Aptana instance, and finding via Windows that Aptana should indeed be opened, and opening a new instance. So I went to Window > Preferences > Editors > File Assocations and entered a new *.php -> Text Editor association.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Aptana Studio are you using?

In Studio 2, there is no default PHP plugin installed, so there is no PHP editor, and until you install the PDT plugin, you will get the above behavior.

In Studio 3, there is a default PHP plugin, so a double-click on a file should open it in the PHP editor.

As pointed out above, once you explicitly pick an editor for a file, it will continue to open in that editor. You can set up file associations here:

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Changing+your+file+association+preferences

Answer (score 0):

Since this is still seems to be a bug in Aptana, this thread:
https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/3707-aptana-opens-a-new-instance-when-i-click-on-a-file
led me to here:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-23?focusedCommentId=151446&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-151446

Which fixed the issue on multiple computers (with fresh installs) for me.